# To extract both tables and normal text from pdf file

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf, text-extraction, python-camelot

I want to extract text from pdf which contains both normal text and tables such that tables will be extracted by camelot and normal text will be extracted by pypdf2.

I tried extracting tables using camelot but sometimes it extracts text present outside the table as well, considering it as a table with one column.

So, how to restrict camelot only to the table extraction and PyPDF2 only to the text present outside the table?

Comment: Why not using a package that can do both: recognizing and extracting table content, but also text, and at the same time being capable to avoid table areas during text extraction ... like [PyMuPDF](https://pypi.org/project/PyMuPDF/)?